# LAN speed not as high as expected

Tags: networking, router, lan, speed

I have an FTP server which I'm accessing through another machine in the LAN, both machines are connected to a 300 Mbit/s router and both machines have a 10/100/1000 Mbit NIC.

With this setup I expect to see speeds of around 40MB/s but actually what I see is 10MB/s (which is my internet connection's speed 80Mbit/s).

Is my understanding wrong or what is happening here?

I can confirm I'm not going through the internet because I'm using LAN addresses to realize the communication.

*EDIT*: I notice that my LAN connection adapter is showing a speed of 100 Mbit/s (in windows network and sharing section), why is that? If I need a giga router in order to achieve speeds higher than 100 mbit then what's the point of 150 300 450 mbit routers at all?

Comment: Are you testing this over Wi-Fi or ethernet?

Comment: @RonMaupin ethernet, sorry forgot to mention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thought I am not sure how you are connecting at 300Mbps over ethernet, unless your entire network is 1000Mbps, or 100Mbps, your maximum transfer speed would be limited by that.

However I don't think this is your issue. 
Depending on the hardware of the computers transferring the data, some processors cannot flood a 100Mbps connection let alone, gigabit.

- What is the type of router you have, and are there any switches in play, maybe a 10Mbps one?
- Could you elaborate on the hardware you are running?

Since I don't have the rep to post a comment.

Comment: There are no switches or anything, I'm using a common [router](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/TL-WR845N.html) both machines are connected to it. The only thing I'm suspecting is the cables, one is not labeled I will switch it with a cat 5e and post soon.

Comment: Ok, so the biggest issue is that the router is only 10/100Mbps:

Interface4 10/100Mbps LAN PORTS
1 10/100Mbps WAN PORT

Comment: @php_nub_qq, you actually _are_ using a switch, albeit one built into the router chassis. The four yellow ports on the back are switch ports, not router ports.

Comment: This means your max transfer rate is roughly 9.9MBps at best through the router. Note the MBps, not Mbps. So it will never be able to transfer at th 40MBps you want.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, but then why is the router labeled 300 Mbit if the maximum speed it can achieve is 100 mbit?

Comment: That is the max Mbps of the wifi, which if you have multiple clients can help prevent bottlenecking.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you are mixing wireless max transmission speeds and wired ethernet speeds.
Ethernet speeds are 10 Mbps,100 Mbps and 1000 Mbps on major hardware made in the last 10 years and those are max speeds possible.
the 300mbps you are reading is the max possible wireless transmission speeds (which never get close to that)
That speed is advertised so the device sells more because most consumers "like big numbers"

you are limited to a max of 100Mbps (minus some overhead) across your network because a network connection can only be as fast as the slowest component.

you are using a "SOHO" router which is a mixture of three major network equipment components; the router, switch and Wireless Access Point or WAP.

also other bottlenecks can occur when transferring at high speeds such as hard drive transfer speed and even size of the file being moved.

you are on a 100Mbps network

> I notice that my LAN connection adapter is showing a speed of 100
>   Mbit/s

and those max transfer speeds are 10-12MBps which is what you are getting.

unless you get a gigabit SOHO router you will not pass the speeds you are getting.